# I want to set wallpaper from horizontally scrolled images using android

Tags: android

Please check my main.xml:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVdisplay"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BsetWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Wallpaper" />
 <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="200dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage1"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage2"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/b" />
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage3"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c" />
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage4"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/d" />
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage5"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/e" />
             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage6"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/f" />
             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage7"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/g" />
             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage8"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/h" />
               <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage9"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/i" />
                 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage10"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/j" />
                   <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage11"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/k" />
                     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage12"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/l" />
                       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage13"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/m" />
                         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVimage14"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/n" />
             </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>             
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have added some images statically and add them in HorizontalScrollView.There is a button for set wallpaper now I want to choose image from that and want to set wallpaper.please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u may need to `setOnClickListener()` on all of your `ImageView`, i would suggest you added your **Images** *programmatically*, that will make your `onClick` event handling easier.

as for setting up wallpaper, you need to declare `android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER` permission at your manifest file. And the following code will set `Bitmap bmp` as wallpaper

```
getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
```